# Haskell add unique combinations of list to tuple

Tags: list, haskell, list-comprehension

Say for example that I have a list like this

```
list = ["AC", "BA"]
```

I would like to add every unique combination of this list to a tuple so the result is like this:

```
[("AC", "AC"),("AC","BA"),("BA", "BA")]
```

where `("BA","AC")` is excluded.

My first approach was to use a list comprehension like this:

```
ya = [(x,y) | x <- list, y <- list]
```

But I couldn't manage to get it to work, is there anyway to achieve my result by using list comprehensions?

Comment: So for a 3 element list `[1, 2, 3]`, you'd want to output `[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 3)]`?

Comment: Exactly! Thanks for the edit btw!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ThreeFx's answer will work, but it adds the constraint that you elements must be orderable.  Instead, you can get away with functions in `Prelude` and `Data.List` to implement this more efficiently and more generically:

```
import Data.List (tails)

permutations2 :: [a] -> [(a, a)]
permutations2 list
    = concat
    $ zipWith (zip . repeat) list
    $ tails list
```

It doesn't use list comprehensions, but it works without having to perform potentially expensive comparisons and without any constraints on what kind of values you can put through it.

---

To see how this works, consider that if you had the list `[1, 2, 3]`, you'd have the groups

```
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3),
         (2, 2), (2, 3),
                 (3, 3)]
```

This is equivalent to

```
[(1, [1, 2, 3]),
 (2,    [2, 3]),
 (3,       [3])]
```

since it doesn't contain any extra or any less information.  The transformation from this form to our desired output is to map the function `f (x, ys) = map (\y -> (x, y)) ys` over each tuple, then `concat` them together.  Now we just need to figure out how to get the second element of those tuples.  Quite clearly, we see that all its doing is dropping successive elements off the front of the list.  Luckily, this is already implemented for us by the `tails` function in `Data.List`.  The first element in each of these tuples is just makes up the original list, so we know we can use a `zip`.  Initially, you could implement this with

```
> concatMap (\(x, ys) -> map (\y -> (x, y)) ys) $ zip list $ tails list
```

But I personally prefer `zip`s, so I'd turn the inner function into one that doesn't use lambdas more than necessary:

```
> concatMap (\(x, ys) -> zip (repeat x) ys) $ zip list $ tails list
```

And since I prefer `zipWith f` over `map (uncurry f) . zip`, I'd turn this into

```
> concat $ zipWith (\x ys -> zip (repeat x) ys) list $ tails list
```

Now, we can reduce this further:

```
> concat $ zipWith (\x -> zip (repeat x)) list $ tails list
> concat $ zipWith (zip . repeat) list $ tails list
```

thanks the eta-reduction and function composition.  We could make this entirely pointfree where

```
> permutations2 = concat . ap (zipWith (zip . repeat)) tails
```

But I find this pretty hard to read and understand, so I think I'll stick with the previous version.

Answer (score 9):

My preferred solution uses a list comprehension

```
f :: [t] -> [(t, t)]
f list = [ (a,b) | theTail@(a:_) <- tails list , b <- theTail ]
```

I find this to be quite readable: first you choose (non-deterministically) a suffix `theTail`, starting with `a`, and then you choose (non-deterministically) an element `b` of the suffix. Finally, the pair `(a,b)` is produced, which clearly ranges over the wanted pairs.

It should also be optimally efficient: every time you demand an element from it, that is produced in constant time.

Comment: *for every element in a list, pair it up with itself and all the elements to its right*: `f xs = [(x,y) | ys@(x:_) <- tails xs, y <- ys]`. List comprehensions are very visual, and `concat` comes effortlessly with them.

Answer (score 3):

Just use a list comprehension:

```
f :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [(a, a)]
f list = [ (a, b) | a <- list, b <- list, a <= b ]
```

Since Haskell's `String` is in the `Ord` typeclass, which means it can be ordered, you first tell Haskell to get all possible combinations and then exclude every combination where `b` is greater than `a` which removes all "duplicate" combinations.

Example output:

```
> f [1,2,3,4]
[(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,2),(2,3),(2,4),(3,3),(3,4),(4,4)]
```